# Migrating a project using @angular-builders/custom-webpack to NX

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, nrwl-nx, angular-builder

I'm trying to migrate [an Angular project](https://github.com/azerothcore/Keira3/) that currently uses the `"@angular-builders/custom-webpack` build targets to [an integrated NX monorepo](https://nx.dev/recipes/angular/migration/angular#migrating-to-an-integrated-nx-monorepo) and during the execution of `npx nx@latest init --integrated` I get the following warning:

> - Unsupported builders:
>
>   - Errors:
>
>     - The "build" target is using a builder "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser" that's not currently
>       supported by the automated migration. The target will be skipped.
>     - The "serve" target is using a builder "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server" that's not currently
>       supported by the automated migration. The target will be skipped.
>     - The "test" target is using a builder "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:karma" that's not currently
>       supported by the automated migration. The target will be skipped.
>   - Make sure to manually migrate the target configuration and any possible associated files. Alternatively, you could revert the
>     migration, change the builder to one of the builders supported by the
>     automated migration ("@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
>     "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
>     "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser-esbuild",
>     "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
>     "@cypress/schematic:cypress",
>     "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
>     "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
>     "@angular-devkit/build-angular:prerender",
>     "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
>     "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
>     "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
>     "@angular-devkit/build-angular:ssr-dev-server",
>     "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma" and
>     "@angular-eslint/builder:lint"), and run the migration again.

what should I do about it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all I had to do was manually fixing the `project.json` file inside `apps/my-app/` and specifically I had to change all values such as:

```
someConf: "src/...",
```

to:

```
someConf: "apps/my-app/src..."
```

I also had to manually fix the `"extends":` property of several `tsconfig.xxx.json` files (moved by NX) pointing to the right base file (which has been renamed to `tsconfig.base.json` by NX).

It surprises me that these were not done automatically by nx (using version `18.0.4`)